# keyword search with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

While building an application I came across a difficult issue I can't resolve.
I'm having a table with several keywords, like:

**structure:**

```
id  keyword
1   iphone 4
2   iphone 4 16gb black
3   iphone 3gs
4   iphone 5 32gb white
5   macbook pro 13" late 2009
6   macbook air 15"
...
```

Now I'm trying to get results from that database using keywords.
e.g. I'm searching for `iphone 4 black`. I tried to do that in this
way: keyword like `%iphone%4%black`, but there I have the problem that the sorting
of the keywords in the `like` matters. So I tried the fulltext-serach of mysql. But this search also returns me e.g. `iphone 3gs`, when searching for `iphone 4`.

Is there a way to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
where keyword like '%iphone%'
and keyword like '%4%'
and keyword like '%black%'
```

Comment: But this would also Return 'iPhone 4s'. Maybe I should append a Space at the beginning and end of a keyword?

Comment: hopefully it's not a big table, because a query like that will be slow.

Comment: It is... So what should I do in that Case?

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple LIKE conditions together:

```
WHERE keyword LIKE '%iphone%' AND keyword LIKE '%4%' AND keyword LIKE '%black%'
```

Then eventually you can actually start to attribute "points" to different matches to order your results by with some fancy IF'ing in your ORDER BY

Comment: But this would also Return 'iPhone 4s'. Maybe I should append a Space at the beginning and end of a keyword?

Comment: a better solution imo is to implement a "-" operator to allow you to include some `NOT LIKE`'s in your sql

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WHERE keyword LIKE %iphone% AND keyword LIKE %black%
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you use the full text option?  It requires a literal in the query?

But, since you tried it, consider using the boolean option (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

This allows you to specify words that must be included or excluded in the search.  In your case, you want to include everything, so you want a search string like "+iphone +4".  You would need to place this directly into the query.

```
where match(keyword) against ('+iphone +4' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: The problem here is that I would get iPhone 4s, too. How can I exclude that?

Comment: Add a space after the "4" in the search string.

Comment: Wouldn't that space exclude instances where "4" is at the end of text?